# Timed Exam test for candidates

Tags: plugins

Please is there any way I can set up a timed Test I can automatically assign scores on WordPress for applicants?

Answer (score 0):

There are no such default features in WordPress but there are so many plugins that can do that it wouldn't be fair to just advise you to one single plugin.

There are paid plugins and free plugins that can do quizzes. Depending on your needs you will need one plugin or the other. Try more than one to see which works best for you. Search for "quiz plugin WordPress" in Google.